# How to check if Neo4J is running on the server?

Tags: cron, neo4j, pid

Is there any way to check whether Neo4J is running using `pidof` command? I tried doing

```
 pidof /path/to/neo4j/bin/neo4j
```

But it didn't seem to work.

I need it to set up a script that I will then launch with cron to make sure that if the database crashes I can restart it again.

Thank you!

Comment: Neo4j creates a pid file in its data directory `data/neo4j-service.pid` that you can use to check the currently running processes against.

Answer (score 6):

`bin/neo4j status` is the command you are looking for.

Comment: `c:\neo4j\bin\neo4j status` gets `'Neo4j is not running.'` if it's only running as a console.

Answer (score 5):

For a more general use, checking whether neo4dj is running or not, use the following command:

```
 service neo4j-service status
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16 04 I can execute the following:

```
sudo service neo4j status
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't work since neo4j is being run by `java` command.

Here's a workaround if you want to do something by yourself:

```
if test -z "$(ps -A | grep neo4j)"
    then
        echo "no neo4j instance running"
    else
        echo "neo4j up and running"
fi
```

But since, as you may probably know, noe4j launcher already does something like that, we may just look at how it's done there:

```
detectrunning() {
  if [ $DIST_OS = "solaris" ] ; then
      ## SmartOS has a different lsof command line arguments
      newpid=$(lsof -o $NEO4J_SERVER_PORT | grep '::' | head -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
  else
      ## This could be achieved with filtering using -sTCP:LISTEN but this option is not available
      ## on lsof v4.78 which is the one bundled with some distros. So we have to do this grep below
      newpid=$(lsof -i :$NEO4J_SERVER_PORT -F T -Ts | grep -i "TST=LISTEN" -B1 | head -n1)
      newpid=${newpid:1}
  fi
}
```

This is an excerpt from the `bin/neo4j` script inside neo4j distribution directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these following ways to get neo4j service status in Windows:

Powershell:

```
Get-Service neo4j
```

CMD/Powershell:

```
service neo4j
```